# Is it possible to play the same audio on two audio output devices simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to make a script that gets the audio from an audio element and plays it on headset and laptop speakers at he same time.
Is this possible?

This is the code that I wrote so far:

```js
const outputs = (await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()).filter(({ kind, deviceId }) => kind === 'audiooutput' && deviceId !== 'default' && deviceId !== 'communications' );
var players = [];
document.querySelectorAll('audio').forEach((y)=>{
    players.push([]); let l = players.length-1;
    outputs.forEach((x)=>{
        if(players[l].length===0) players[l].push(y);
        else {
            let p = y.cloneNode();
            p.srcObject = players[l][0].srcObject.clone();
            players[l].push(p);
        }
    });
})
players.forEach((a)=>{
    a.forEach((o, i)=>{
        o.setSinkId(outputs[i].deviceId);
        o.play();
    })
})
```

The issue with this code is that it makes the audio only play on the other speaker instead of playing it on both.

Note that the window has access to mic so I can see all the devices from `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`.
The script is intended to work mainly on Edge and Chrome.

Comment: While this is probably not possible, I would not do this even if it was. You don't have control over the users chosen audio output, nor should you.

Comment: The point of doing this is to increase audio loudness without getting distortion. I'm using headset only for testing. The real world scenario would be using laptop speakers plus external usb speaker.

Comment: No you cant, the user is in control.

Comment: @Grumpy What do you mean by the user? If the user is me, can I do this? Or you mean js can't, only the user can do this manually (through virtual audio cable maybe)

Comment: The user is in control, the user chooses the ouput, as it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution!
Since I wasn't able to play sound on multiple devices at once in the same window I managed to get this done by creating iframes that contain audio elements.
Then I set to all of those audio elements the same source and I set them to output audio a specific device and I sync the play/stop with event listeners.

This works because iframes are separated by the main window. Actually I think they get their own process (on chromium browsers).

My code looks like this: (note I'm not using static sources, but srcObjects)

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then(s=>{
    s.getTracks().forEach(x=>x.stop()); //stop mic use because we need only outputs
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(o=>{
        const outputs = o.filter(({ kind, deviceId }) => kind === 'audiooutput' && deviceId !== 'default' && deviceId !== 'communications');

        let audioSrc = getAudioSrc(), players = [];

        audioSrc.src.pause(); // Pause source to start audio in sync ?
        audioSrc.src.addEventListener("pause", () => players.forEach(x=>x.pause()));
        audioSrc.src.addEventListener("play", () => players.forEach(x=>x.play()));

        outputs.forEach((x)=>{
            let ifrm = makeIFrame(), audioEl = makeAudio(ifrm.document, audioSrc.s, x.deviceId);
            players.push(audioEl);
        });
    });
}).catch(e=>console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create two `AudioContext`s for this, each with their own output devices (specified by `sinkId`).

```js
function playSound(sinkId, frequency) {
  // plays one second of sine wave
  // through an output device with given sinkId
  let audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)({ sinkId: sinkId });
  let oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
  oscillator.frequency.value = frequency;
  oscillator.connect(audioContext.destination);
  oscillator.start();
  setTimeout(() => {
    oscillator.stop();
    audioContext.close();
  }, 1000);
}

playSound("sinkIdA", 440);
playSound("sinkIdB", 880);  // will play at the same time as above
```